# Why do this fail? Perl string comparison

Tags: perl

I want to have a simple do you want to continue dialog in my pl script. It looks like this:

```
print "continue? (Y/n)\r\n";
$ans = <>;
if("$ans" eq "n"){
    print "$ans";
    exit 0;
}
print "still here";
```

If I write a n it does not enter the if statement, why? Is exit 0; the correct way to exit the program?. If I just print the $ans variable it prints the n that I typed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

```
chomp $ans;
```

you should strip \n

Demo:

```
print "continue? (Y/n)\r\n";
$ans = <>;
chomp $ans;
if("$ans" eq "n"){
    print "$ans";
    exit 0;
}
print "still here";
```

Comment: if((chomp $ans) eq "n"){
 print "$ans";
 exit 0;
}
this still prints the "still here" :/ and no n

Comment: What `chomp` returned *is not* modified string. see [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Comment: @TheDMerged `chomp $ans` doesn't return a modified $ans, you need to call it in a separate expression, and afterward compare $ans.

Comment: @TheDMerged: You should be adding 'use warnings' and 'use strict' to your scripts.  If you do that you'll see "Can't modify string in chomp...".  If you want to shorten it, you can write `chomp( my $ans = <> );`